# How to remove the 'PS' message that appears in the terminal after running code in VS Code

Tags: java, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I am currently taking Java lessons and I am using VSCode. I wrote this code:

```
class Simple{  
    public static void main(String args[]){  
     System.out.println("Hello World!");  
    }   }
```

But the thing is every time I run my code a message appears:

```
Windows PowerShell Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS D:\Visual Studio Code\Java Practice>  & 'c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-java-debug-0.26.0\scripts\launcher.bat' 'ripts\launcher.bat' 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\AdoptOpenJDK\bin\java.exe' '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' '-cData\Roaming\Code\Usep' 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\3be13cab7faa4596286e209d09d9be11\redhat.java\jdt_ws\Java Practice_fb59611a\bin' 'Simple' Hello World! PS D:\Visual Studio Code\Java Practice>
```

I only want to see my output, which in this case is 'Hello World!'. Is there a way to remove the other lines?

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Debug (Launch) - Current File",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": "",
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "mainClass": "${file}"
        },
    ]
}
```

Add this to your `launch.json` file. The important option for you here is `"console": "internalConsole",` This will output everything to the **Debug Console** tab and not terminal. And it will look clean like this.

[image: Output in debug console]

Comment: I added it to my launch.json file as you said but it didn't solve it, I am still getting the same thing.

Comment: does you `launch.json` have any other configurations? if so choose this when you are launching, otherwise to test, remove everything and paste just this and try.